# I'm unable to create password. I am able to create new username but will not let me type in password. I've read previous posts, still confused

Tags: password

Hey everyone trying to get ubuntu installed, like the title says able to create username but it will not let me type in password. I've read it's a security feature and I've tried typing in other prompts, but it will still not let me type in anything when it comes to the password. Please help!

Comment: Ok. First things first. How are you creating the new user?. CLI (useradd, adduser) or some graphical application. Did you create a no-password user? Did you remove the password (e.g. password -d user)?

Answer (score 0):

**Ignore that the cursor does not move. The system IS detecting your keystrokes.** That's deliberate -- it's supposed to act that way.

Simply type your correct password.

Hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after typing your password.